# How to assign a number to a value falling in a certain bin

Tags: python, pandas

I have a continuous variable and I am trying to create 10 bins on this variable. This variable has more than 50% zero values so I create bins that are uneven in size using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pandas.core.algorithms as algos
from pandas import Series
bins = algos.quantile(np.unique(df['highlight']), np.linspace(0, 1, 11))
result = pd.tools.tile._bins_to_cuts(df['highlight'], bins, include_lowest=True)
result.value_counts()

[0, 78.3]         2152235
(78.3, 156.6]       93257
(156.6, 234.9]      37539
(234.9, 313.2]      17740
(313.2, 391.5]      11781
(391.5, 478.8]       8334
(478.8, 577.2]       7503
(577.2, 711.4]       6216
(711.4, 890.4]       6184
(890.4, 4972]        5539
Name: highlight, dtype: int64
```

As we can see I have the different bins created, now I just want to assign a number to each bin and therefore to the values in the variable. I eventually want the values replaced by the bin number in the same variable.

For example:

A value of 38 will get bin #1

A value of 97 will get bin #2

and so on..

How do I do that?

Comment: map, merge, join

Comment: Use IntervalIndex if it is not already so (pd.cut returns IntervalIndex but you are using private functions so I am not sure).

Answer (score 0):

```
result['assigned'] = np.where(result = '[0, 78.3]', 1, 0)
result['assigned'] = np.where(result = '(78.3, 156.6]', 2, result['assigned'])
result['assigned'] = np.where(result = '(156.6, 234.9]', 3, result['assigned'])
...
```

Comment: While the code snippet may solve the question it is better to provide some description that discloses issue cause and proposed solution.