# How to assign a specific value to a bin in histogram in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

Dear Computer Scientist Family

I was wondering is it possible to assign any value I give to a certain bin, in a histogram. If you notice in my code it will produce a histogram with 2 bins populated with a quantity of 1.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat May  9 20:23:51 2020

@author: DeAngelo
"""

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math





fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
a = np.array([11,75])
ax.hist(a, bins = [0,25,50,75,100])
ax.set_title("histogram of result")
ax.set_xticks([0,25,50,75,100])
ax.set_xlabel('marks')
ax.set_ylabel('no. of students')
plt.show()
```

[image]

First could you theoretically tell the computer that you want to place the value that was assigned in the 75-100 bin. And move it to the 0-25 bin. Meaning I now would now have 2 entries in the 0-25 bin. But my array would still be `a=[11,75]`

Also another example would be say I have an array 'b=np.array[3]' and I plotted this on my histogram. I know that this would be given the bin 0-25, but could I tell the computer to put this in the 75-100 bin?

**If so how?**

Second what about the average I know you can use `np.mean(a)` to calculate the average. But say I wanted to put that value in the bin that corresponds to 75-100. Would that be possible?

I looked at this code [How to assign a number to a value falling in a certain bin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48085956/how-to-assign-a-number-to-a-value-falling-in-a-certain-bin) , but that was in **Ancient Egyptian hieroglyphics** and unfortunately my degree is in physics and not that.

If you can help me with this it would mean a lot to me.**<3**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A histogram is just represented as a bar chart, so you could manipulate the bar values. Here you can precalculate the histogram and plot it as a bar chart:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

a = np.array([11,75])
# calculate histogram values
vals, bins = np.histogram(a, bins = [0,25,50,75,100])
width = np.ediff1d(bins)

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

# plot histogram values as bar chart
ax.bar(bins[:-1] + width/2, vals, width)
ax.set_title("histogram of result")
ax.set_xticks([0,25,50,75,100])
ax.set_xlabel('marks')
ax.set_ylabel('no. of students')
plt.show()
```

[image: reproduced example]

This gives you your example. You can now however manipulate the bar values before plotting should you so wish:

```
# the bin values
vals 
>>> array([1, 0, 0, 1])

# bin edges
bins
>>> array([  0,  25,  50,  75, 100])

# do manipulation -> remove one count from 75-100 bin and put in 0-25 bin
vals[-1] -= 1
vals[0] += 1

# plot new graph
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

# plot histogram values as bar chart
ax.bar(bins[:-1] + width/2, vals, width)
ax.set_title("histogram of result")
ax.set_xticks([0,25,50,75,100])
ax.set_xlabel('marks')
ax.set_ylabel('no. of students')
plt.show()
```

[image: example]

I have to comment, what are your reasons for doing this? In your example you want to calculate the average and put it in the wrong bin. You can certainly do that as I have shown above, but I'm not sure what it means at that point?

Comment: hello @paddyharrison The reason I am doing that is because I am using liner interoplation to create a histogram chart but my y values don't fall into the create bin. 

If you go here [link] (http://www.oecd-nea.org/janisweb/)
and click on alpha induced cross sections

Then you scroll up and on the left hand side you click 8-O
Then you click 8-O-17

Then you go to the lower middle part you will see 
**JENDL/AN-2005 / Cross sections / O17 / MT=4 : (z,n') / Cross section** go to display and click T. another tab will open and it will have Ke, σ(e). I want to make a histogram using those.

Comment: Now lets say I would create a bin for the KE from 1.25 to 1.5 Mev. I would compute the mean of σ(e) that correspond to those range of values and place it within that bin, but the problem is the value does not lay perfectly within 1.25-1.5. 

Say the value of  σ(e) =.3 I want to place that value in the 1.25-1.5 bin. 

If you can think of a better way to do this any help is much appreciated :) thank you

Comment: So you want to define a set of bins and compute an average value for them?

Comment: Or do you want to generate some random values from the linked data?

Comment: _So you want to define a set of bins and compute an average value for them?_    This is what I want to do. and the averages of a certain σ(e) would go into a certain bin.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. You can catch the return value of the histogram function by assigning it to a variable:

```py
h = ax.hist(a, bins = [0, 25, 50, 75, 100])
h
```

```py
(array([1., 0., 0., 1.]),
 array([  0,  25,  50,  75, 100]),
 <a list of 4 Patch objects>)
```

As the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.hist.html) says, this "is a tuple (n, bins, patches)". 
We are only interested in the counts and bins, so let's assign them to individual variables:

```py
counts, bins, _ = h
```

Now you can manipulate the counts in any way you like, e.g. move one count from the fourth to the first bin:

```py
counts[3] -= 1
counts[0] += 1
counts
```

```py
array([2., 0., 0., 0.])
```

We can turn these data into a histogram plot as shown in the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.hist.html) under the `weights` parameter:

```py
plt.hist(bins[:-1], bins, weights=counts);
```

[image: histogram example]